# How do you achieve this backwards div effect?

Tags: html, css

How do you make text go *backwards* instead of *forwards*?

Look at these two below pictures...

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

---

[image: #2 Visual Aid]

Normally, I would create a div that has `no width` and `white-space: nowrap` to create text that moves *forward*. Notice, the arrow is in the same place for both pictures, but the text moves more backwards for the second picture. **How do I achieve this same effect with CSS?**

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Many, many ways. `float:right;`, `text-align:right;`, etc.

Comment: Without any code of yours (HTML/CSS) answers can be anything and far from what you have and need and you won'nt know where you went wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using right floating on a series of child elements:

```css
span {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Text 1</span>
    <span>Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span>Text 4</span>
    <span>Text 5</span>
</div>
```

Or using `direction:rtl`:

```css
div {
    direction: rtl;
}
span {
    direction: ltr;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Text 1</span>
    <span>Text 2</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
    <span>Text 4</span>
    <span>Text 5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! How would you do the same thing with images?

Comment: @JackMan It is the same process. You replace the span tags with img tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: right;` **or** `text-align: right;`

There's plenty of solutions to do this.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: please , not w3school , too many bad and obsolete tips out there and the most **it has nothing to do with W3C** confusing domain name ...

Comment: Great answer! How would you do the same thing with images?

Comment: I would personally use `float` for images. Sometimes with images, I find that they add a margin of their own, so I would also set `display: block;`